# Create banner inside a hero image

Tags: css

I'm new in CSS and I have a simple CSS grid responsive hero, and I want to add a simple banner at the middle-right with some text with white background and 0.5 opacity

[image]

I created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Gerry123/pen/WNpjNQQ) with example

```css
.hero-section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr; // stretch to the full frame
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  .banner-image-div {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  } // image
  .banner-overlay-div {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  } // gradient or other overlay
  .banner-text-div {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  }
}

.hero {
  display: grid;
  min-width: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 968px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.hero-rectangle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 250px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #fffff;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero-section">
  <div class="row" style="padding: 0 15px; margin: 0px auto; background-color: #fff">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="banner-image-div">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="" class="hero" />
        <div class="hero-rectangle">
          <p>Text here </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I try to do that but can not place it above the hero image. How can I position it? Regards

Comment: 0.3 and 0.7 for opacity are two numbers I tend to use a lot of opacity. For the background-color of `.hero-rectangle`, I would go with `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the your positioning properties within the `hero-rectangle` element to position it properly. I also added:

```css
.banner-image-div {
  position: relative;
}
```

To make the bubbling for the position absolute the image container.

**MDN:** *The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned **relative** to its closest positioned ancestor, (element with **`position: absolute;`**), if any otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.*

```css
.hero-section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr; // stretch to the full frame
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  .banner-image-div {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  } // image
  .banner-overlay-div {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  } // gradient or other overlay
  .banner-text-div {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  }
}

.hero {
  display: grid;
  min-width: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 968px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.banner-image-div {
  position: relative;
}

.hero-rectangle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 250px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25%;
  top: 35%;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero-section">
  <div class="row" style="padding: 0 15px; margin: 0px auto; background-color: #fff">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="banner-image-div">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="" class="hero" />
        <div class="hero-rectangle">
          <p>Text here </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

As absolute elements are positioned relatively to their closest `relative` positioned ancestor, in order to position your `absolute` element, you need to:

1. Make its parent (`.banner-image-div`) have `position: relative`.
2. Add the `top` and `left` properties to your `.hero-rectangle` style.

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.child {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
}

.parent.well-defined {
  position: relative;
}

.child.well-defined {
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    I'm not positioned well :(
  </div>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div class="parent well-defined">
  <div class="child well-defined">
    I'm well positioned :)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In order to position the element in the middle vertically, you need to add `top: 50%` and then `transform: translateY(-50%)`.